# stackoverflow.com without OpenID

Tags: discussion, openid

is it possible to login/create user in stackoverflow.com without creating/login using OpenID?
i hate using OpenID, it's really confusing if you create different user/account on different websites :(

> Note: the following text was submitted as an edit suggestion. I approved it, giving the user the benefit of the doubt and assuming that it was the OP's other account. -[Popular Demand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/131713/popular-demand)

even when i want to post this question under my new openid, i still logged as the old user,
so i can't view my own question when i logged under my userid

Comment: OpenID is currently the only way to login to StackOverflow...but I'm thrown by your comments: "it's really confusing if you create different user/account on different websites".  That's exactly what OpenID *doesn't* do, can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: i used to have one e-mail, it was hacked and i cannot use it anymore, so i create another id for stackoverflow, but the site recognize me as an openid user with the old email...

Comment: or when i create a blog, one for personal use and the other for work, the blog usually confused me with my other openid

Comment: why can't it be simple, using username and e-mail to log-in/ create account? it feels like openid is watching my every online activities

Comment: you can open new question with that problem of yours (new open ID not recognized) it will get more and better attention.

Answer (score 2):

> it's really confusing if you create
>   different user/account on different
>   websites

That's right! If all websites **will** use OpenID it means one single account for all websites. Your dream come true. So you're contradicting yourself here.

Anyhow, until this happens just treat `www.myopenid.com` as another website that you have to register to.

And just between us..... don't you have `gmail`, `yahoo!` or (*shudders*) `Facebook`? Come on! :)

Comment: I have to agree with the OP on the security issue: if your OpenID account is compromised, then **EVERY** website you ever used that OpenID for is also compromised. In addition, some people may have a legitimate concern: do I want one entity to know all of my web site usage patterns? I like OpenID and I too have implemented it for [my web site](http://www.mydevarmy.com), but I still think about those issues...

Comment: @Lirik he never mentioned security, just that's it's "confusing". Regarding this issue, most people have the same password anyway for everything so it's not any worse. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizzard: the OP is also known as pandr01d (he commented with those concerns above). True that most people have a single password, but there is no centralized location where somebody can see which web sites you ID with it. Like I said, I like OpenID and I implemented it on my web site as the only way to log in, I'm just saying that the OP is not entirely without a point.

Comment: no i mean i have two e-mail one for work and the other for personal use, openid is linking the two of them in one account..

Comment: why is my edit doesn't show? it says "need peer review"??

Comment: see? one example is when i want to post a question as pandr01d, it comes up as other user :(

Comment: @pandr01d you have less than 100 points so you can't edit yet. You need more rep to edit.

Comment: @pand nobody can see your email addresses here if that's what you're concerned about. To have account removed from this website send email to team@stackoverflow.com

Comment: okay, so here is my edit: i know the point of using an OpenID, is to use one ID for every online activities(blog, email, facebook etc), what i want is keep different user on different site... how is that contradicting?? and i don't understand when someone choose vote down, is my question too dumb?

Comment: i know the e-mail is hidden, it says
"never displayed, optional notifications, used for gravatar" on edit account page..

Comment: it's just i want it separated... openid is a nightmare for me, it feels like having a conjoined twins >.<

Comment: to anyone who convert my old account to my new one, thank you so much! :D now i can see my old thread

Comment: just a suggestion, for a site using openid for everything, why do i have to re-login to every stackoverflow sub-site(e.g. cooking, gamedevelopment, math)? why not using one login for every stackoverflow site?

Comment: @pand I don't know how it works technically - but why separate accounts in the same network? It really makes zero sense. You were downvoted by me because I simply don't agree with your request that's all. Nothing personal. :)

Comment: um.. not separate accounts in the same network, separate OpenID, because OpenID is used for other websites like wordpress or facebook. two email=two ID, openID mushed two of them in one

Comment: what do you mean separate accounts? more example : i don't want to use my work (ID0) when using stackoverflow, so i use ID1(my personal ID --not work related), OpenID automatically join both ID so when i post in stackoverflow, those two ID gets swapped..

Comment: i'm not using separate accounts/ two ID to mess with people

Comment: how can i explain this better?

Comment: i didn't suggest you change about the whole way you login, i just want an alternative so that without an OpenID, i still can use the site. but it's just a suggestion, and i sent it because it says "feedback always welcome"

Comment: @pan feedbacks *are* welcome, but it doesn't mean many people will agree with them. Nobody told you "don't say this" or flamed you. :) Regarding the discussion, OpenID can't really "merge" two accounts unless you done something yourself - but this is matter more fit for `OpenID` support forum, Stack Overflow is not responsible for that platform it's just using it. Regarding logging in, like I said in the answer, just think you're registering to www.myopenid.com website and using that same account you created there in here.

Comment: so that means if i want to use stackoverflow, i must use an openid?

Comment: @pand yes that was already said clearly in Nick Craver first comment on your question: "OpenID is currently the only way to login to StackOverflow."

Comment: @pand on second thought, you don't really **have** to login or register.. you can ask question, answer question and Accept answers to your questions without any account - you won't be able to vote though. This is all saved in local cookie on your machine.