# Logging in to StackOverflow without OpenID

Tags: support, stack-overflow, openid

I'm asking almost exactly [this same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83023/stackoverflow-com-without-openid) but this time not because I'm confused with OpenID but because I have it blocked at work so I can only browse SO from work but not ask/answer a question.

Is there any way I could login in StackOverflow without using OpenID or any good proxy you know or use to go through the login at work?

Comment: Theoretically, using Stack Exchange's own OpenID provider ought to work for you. Or is that also blocked? But then would most of Stack Overflow also not work for you at all... Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I have the OpenID URLs blocked, as I see the errors in the ajax posts everytime I click in every OpenID provider on the login list. I'll capture them tomorrow at work so I can attach them to the question.

Comment: If you manually browse to https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login what you get? If it works, just use this to log in manually..

Comment: @Sha Dow Wiz Ard: I tried to go to that URL from work and after filling the email/password fields I appear as logged in but then I don't see a way to navigate back to any stackexchange keeping the session cookie so even if I appear as logged in at openid.stackexchange.com/user/, when I load the meta.stackoverflow.com I don't seem to be logged in.

Comment: Really weird.. not familiar enough with the mechanics of OpenID so can't really know what's going on. :/